# Need help using Net::SSH::Expect module to provide password / yes/ no interaction

Tags: perl

Ok what i am looking for here is to do the following.

> 1. Login in to the remote server.
> 2. Execute a few cmds.
> 3. Interaction such as yes/no to generate keys.

Answer (score 1):

### CPAN Documentation is a Good Resource

As I discussed with you earlier in [perl chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/34988/perl), this module is [well documented on CPAN](https://metacpan.org/pod/Net::SSH::Expect). Using some of the examples from there...

To configure `Net::SSH::Expect` for your server:

```
my $ssh = Net::SSH::Expect->new (
    host => "myserver.com",
    password=> 'pass87word',
    user => 'bnegrao',
    raw_pty => 1
);
```

To log in using password:

```
my $login_output = $ssh->login();
if ($login_output !~ /Welcome/) {
    die "Login has failed. Login output was $login_output";
}
```

To run commands:

```
my $ls = $ssh->exec("ls -l /");
print($ls);
 
my $who = $ssh->exec("who");
print ($who);
```

To close connection:

```
$ssh->close();
```

You should really ask if you have more specific questions, as just asking for examples isn't really going to help you in accomplishing your task. The documentation is also very complete, so you should check there.

Comment: The issue i faced was "SSHAuthenticationError Login timed out." Looks like the remote server's SSH key was already in the server and hence i did not have to authenticate. Works fine..